# Running install process from c# wpf application

Tags: c#, process, nsis

In my C# WPF Application in statup process I'm checking whether the installation of new version is required. If so, I want to break current process and start installer. The installer is developed using NSIS package.
The problem is that sometimes  only User Account Control dialog from NSIS installer appears and install process breaks.

[image]

How to ensure that the installation process is executed every time?

Here is my code on Application Startup.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Disable shutdown when the dialog closes
            Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

            if ( IfUpdateRequired())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(sessionCtx.AutoUpdateVersionInfo.SetupPath);
                //This should not block current program
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;  
                startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
                this.Shutdown();
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnStartup(e);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps add a screenshot of "start screen notifying system modification" because I don't really understand what you are talking about.

Comment: I mean "User Account Control dialog".

Comment: What happens when "install process breaks"? Are there any error messages or anything like that?

Comment: There is no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only guess is that the child process has not fully started before your process quits. ShellExecute is allowed to perform its operation asynchronously.

If this is the cause then you should be able to work around it by sleeping a bit before calling `this.Shutdown()`. Wait 10 seconds or so perhaps? Or call `WaitForInputIdle(9999)` on the process. Or maybe you could check the Responding process property?

Comment: It seems that your proposal solves the problem. Thanks a lot.